# jQuery accordion panel wont collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

the goal is to have each Section start off in a collapsed state. Panel 0 and 2 both starts off in a collapsed state but panel 1 does not start off in a collapsed state but does collapse when clicked. Panel 1 uses an iframe that contains the live twitter feed imported into the site.

code examples below:

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="testimonials col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <h1>section 1</h1>
        <p>this is a div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="social col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h1>section 2</h1>
        <a class="twitter-timeline" width="100%" data-chrome="transparent noscrollbar" href="https://twitter.com/xxxxxx" data-widget-id="999999">
            Tweets by @xxxxxx
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="news col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h1>section 3</h1>
        <p>this is a div</p>
    </div>

 the javascript

 <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); $(document).ready(function()
        { 

            $(".accordion").accordion({
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                header: "h1"
            });

            //getter variables
            var active = $(".accordion").accordion("option","active");
            var collapsible = $(".accordion").accordion("option","collapsible");
            var header = $(".accordion").accordion("option","header");

            $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 4000, cycle: true }); 
        }); // ]]>
```

Comment: you have script tags in your original code , dont you :\ ?

Comment: Do you really have `r code here` in your real code?

Comment: yes i do have script tags in the original code

Comment: What is the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/dcRQr/

Comment: hahaha i see you @LeeTaylor i forgot to take that out

Comment: @PSL The twitter feed will not start off in a collapsed state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. after each header is the tag containing the content. If you want to make the content act right you need a block level element. after which you can manually set the height using the heightStyle variable. 
If you ever run into this problem, make sure the header's sibling is a block level element.

for example

```
<div class="accordion">
<div class="testimonials col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <h1>section 1</h1>
    <p>this is a div</p>
</div>
<div class="social col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <h1>section 2</h1>
    <div class="social-wrap">
         <a class="twitter-timeline" width="100%" data-chrome="transparent noscrollbar" href="https://twitter.com/xxxxxx" data-widget-id="999999">
        Tweets by @xxxxxx
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="news col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <h1>section 3</h1>
    <p>this is a div</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have this form

```
 <h3>Section 1</h3>
<div>
body 
</div>
```

the body is what is hidden and to access it you need a header to it

Comment: can you please expain your answer a little bit more

Comment: it's not really a must to have this specific arrangement .

Comment: it was originally a div which is why the text says this is a div I tested the p tags and they work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery UI accordion plugin does not allow you to collapse all regions. By definition, an accordion always shows one expanded region. If you want to be able to collapse all regions then you do not want to use accordion, you want to create collapsable regions.

Comment: Incorrect. See [the collapsible demo](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible) in the jQueryUI docs.

Comment: Not exactly because that is why i set the collapsible to true. I works when i have a p tag set up in all collapsible regions but it doesnt work when i have the iframe setup

Comment: Interesting. That must be a relatively new feature. The version of accordion that was around in 2010 did not have that feature. Thanks for pointing that out :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it did have that feature, although it was previously called `alwaysOpen` or something similar.